# Postgres st_difference take too long for execution for n number of polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, postgis

I have 100K polygons and would like to do st_difference on each polygon with type `"TA"` and `"SA"`. I have below query and it takes too long for execution-

```
SELECT (COALESCE(ST_Difference(tna_p.tna, sa_p.sa))) 
         FROM
           (SELECT (shape) AS tna
            FROM io
            WHERE id ='3586de5a'
              AND LOWER(type) =LOWER('TA')) AS tna_p,
           (SELECT st_union(shape) AS sa
            FROM io
            WHERE id ='3586de5a'
              AND LOWER(type) =LOWER('SA')) AS sa_p
```

Explain Analyze for 10 polygons:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=2.22..4.75 rows=1 width=8) (actual 
time=0.371..0.819 
rows=3 loops=1)"
Seq Scan on io  (cost=0.00..2.22 rows=1 width=41) (actual 
time=0.023..0.039 rows=3 loops=1)"
Filter: ((id = '3586de5a'::text)  AND (lower((type)::text) = 
'TNA'::text))"
Rows Removed by Filter: 58"
Aggregate  (cost=2.22..2.23 rows=1 width=32) (actual 
time=0.086..0.086 
rows=1 loops=3)"
Seq Scan on io io_1  (cost=0.00..2.22 rows=1 width=41) (actual 
time=0.005..0.016 rows=3 loops=3)"
Filter: ((id = '3586de5a'::text) AND (lower((type)::text) = 
’SA’::text))"
Rows Removed by Filter: 58"
Planning time: 0.477 ms"
Execution time: 6.960 ms"
```

What would be the best way to do it? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for this query look like?

Comment: I couldn't perform EXPLAIN ANALYZE  on 100k polygons as its taking lot of time.

Comment: Trry with fewer. See where the time is spent.

Comment: Updated in the post, it was too long to add in comments.

Comment: All those sequence scans are your problem. My guess is that you need an expression index on lower(type), possibly on id, and your COALESCE statement is wrong, as it is missing the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @CuriousMaverick Well, a few more than 10 polygons would provide a more useful `EXPLAIN`; try 1000. I notice that there is no join condition. If you want to intersect each polygon with each other, that will be a lot of intersections and a lot of result rows. That could explain the long duration.

Comment: I have an index, i realized it was not eable in RDS. I have enabled it now, still its taking long time. I am guessings because of nested loop.